# Linking problems with GLFW MinGW

Tags: c, codeblocks, linker-errors, glfw

I'm having some linking problems with GLFW (version 3.1) in Code::blocks. I've done a lot of searching around and nothing I can find seems to be correcting anything.
I am currently using the 32-bit binary of the library and have these linker options in my project

```
-lmingw32  -lglew32 -lglfw3 -lopengl32 -lglu32 -lgdi32
```

I've been gettin' a little frustrated, as the majority of the questions from other people I've looked into have always had the problem be that they where missing gdi32, but that isn't the case here, but I can't figure out what is.

The error I am getting is

```
undefined reference to 'glfwInit'
```

If anyone has any idea as to what I might be doing wrong, I would greatly appreciate some assistance.

Edit:
I had forgotten to try and test a glfw function (glfwInit and glfwTerminate) in the actual project I was working on and I tried that out just now and it worked fine. I did a test by just calling a glfw function in my winmain function and it worked fine. The problem occurs only when I am calling a function in a static library that I made which calls glfwInit(), and that is the one that is being left undefined. I assumed that if I included and linked to glfw in my current project, then other libraries I am using would also be able to call glfw functions, is that not the case?

Another note. If I include glfw3.h in the file in the static library that references the glfw function it works fine, but that file is already including a precompiled header that includes glfw3.h so it should work even without explicitly including glf3.h in the file shouldn't it?

Comment: Did you copy the `.dll` file for your library GLFW in bin of your project

Comment: Try repeating `-lglfw3` at the end of the linkage flags, so that the linker re-examines the lib one more time (that's assuming that `glfwInit` is located in that lib). In general, the linker unfortunately only resolves left to right and not both ways; which means that the order of the library statements is crucial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I got this figured out! The problem wasn't actually that my project couldn't link to glfw properly, it could link fine. The problem was that it wasn't just linking to my project though, I had another static library I had written, and that library was calling glfw functions. Now, I had been adding all my libraries through "Other linker options" In CodeBlocks except for my static library, I was linking that one in the "Link Libraries" Box. I can only assume that this made it so that it was linking to my library and glfw in the wrong order, but I'm pretty sure that's what was going down.

Answer (score 0):

Well, [GLFW](http://www.glfw.org/) has a [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/) build system. So you can navigate to your GLFW source code and do the following to build the example "boing":

```
C:\glfw-3.1>mkdir build

C:\glfw-3.1>cd build

C:\glfw-3.1\build>cmake -G "CodeBlocks - MinGW Makefiles" ..\
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.3
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/winbuilds/bin/gcc.exe
-- Check for working C compiler: C:/winbuilds/bin/gcc.exe -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Found OpenGL: opengl32
-- Looking for include file pthread.h
-- Looking for include file pthread.h - found
-- Looking for pthread_create
-- Looking for pthread_create - found
-- Found Threads: TRUE
-- Found Doxygen: C:/Work/env/doxygen-1.8.8/bin/doxygen.exe (found version "1.8.8")
-- Performing Test _GLFW_HAS_DEP
-- Performing Test _GLFW_HAS_DEP - Success
-- Performing Test _GLFW_HAS_ASLR
-- Performing Test _GLFW_HAS_ASLR - Success
-- Performing Test _GLFW_HAS_64ASLR
-- Performing Test _GLFW_HAS_64ASLR - Failed
-- Using Win32 for window creation
-- Using WGL for context creation
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: C:/Users/Brian.sidebotham/Desktop/glfw-3.1/glfw-3.1/build

C:\glfw-3.1\build>mingw32-make boing VERBOSE=ON
```

After some initial output for building GFLW itself you get the build commands for the "boing" example, and in particular the link command:

```
C:\winbuilds\bin\gcc.exe -mwindows -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\boing.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o boing.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libboing.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  ..\src\libglfw3.a -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32
```

and so, that's what you'll be looking to mimic for a static library. If you're wanting to link against a DLL then do the same, but include -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=ON when configuring with CMake and you get the following link:

```
C:\winbuilds\bin\gcc.exe -mwindows -Wl,--whole-archive CMakeFiles\boing.dir/objects.a -Wl,--no-whole-archive  -o boing.exe -Wl,--out-implib,libboing.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0  ..\src\glfw3dll.a -lglu32 -lopengl32 -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32
```

Let us know if you have any more issues. The examples are working well for me.

Comment: Oh thanks for pointing that out, I'd never thought of using CMake to show the build options used in example project. After a bit of a break however, I tested something out and now I don't think I diagnosed my problem properly before, I've edited my question a bit to elaborate.